# C# WPF TextBox displays double.PositiveInfinity as symbol not as text in Win10

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

in Win7 when I set a property to double.PositiveInfinity the textBox is showing "Infinity". In Win10 it is showing an infinity symbol (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221e/index.htm).

I would like to have equal behaviour, or better, always text shown instead of the symbol, no matter what os I use.

Is it possible? And why did the behaviour changed?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx)?
It returns a string that represents the current object. Ok that doesn't work.

Test the value of positive infinity then put a string in the textbox instead

Comment: Yes, I did. When I set double.PositiveInfinity.ToString() the textBox shows "Infinity" in Win7 and the infinity symbol in Win10.

Comment: @iop after some quick testing, I don't believe there's a way to do it without adding more code. I think you're going to need to test for IsPositiveInfinity then add a string to the textbox rather than just input positive infinity.

Comment: Yes, this would work, you are right, but it is not culture independent, e.g. "unendlich" (de-de), "Infinity" (us-en).